How many skill proficiences does an Outlander dragonborn warlock have?
I just need a bit of help.  I'm trying to figure out how many skill proficiencies I should have being a silver dragonborn warlock with the Outlander background.

Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Your race, class, and background tell you exactly what proficiencies, you receive. Is there something particular about those features that is unclear? Without more details about what is confusing you, this reads more like a “do my homework for me” sort of question.

Did you look it up on D&D Beyond? Do you have the Players Handbook available to look at?  Do you have the Basic Rules to Look at?  Welcome to RPGSE . The [Tour], [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] provide guidance on how to get the most out of this site.  Questions do require research before asking.

This may be a lazy question but is that a reason for closure these days? It's a pretty clear question

@SeriousBri It's not that it's a lazy question per-se, it's that it also happens to be very similar to other questions.  One of the main purposes of the Stack Overflow format is to create a knowledgebase usable by future searchers, and this question is not really of any value for that.  We already have other questions about how many skill proficiencies a starting character should get, and the answers for all of them could be just as well applied to this problem.  In this respect, it's similar to a duplicate question.

@PhoenixDuck then we close as a duplicate, or direct the op to the other question, we don't close with 'unclear'. The purpose of this site is to be helpful, this isn't helpful.

@SeriousBri I fully agree.

Four skill proficiencies.
The rules are quite straightforward, if you consult each of the relevant sections of the Player's Handbook. The Basic Rules or System Reference Document will also give you the relevant rules, although the Outlander background in specific is omitted from these sources.
As a warlock, you gain two skill proficiencies chosen from a list:

Skills: Choose two skills from Arcana, Deception, History, Intimidation, Investigation, Nature, and Religion

Dragonborn doesn't give you any skill proficiencies.
The Outlander background gives two additional skill proficiencies. Backgrounds in general grant two:

Each background gives a character proficiency in two skills.

Which for Outlander is both of these:

Skill Proficiencies: Athletics, Survival

Further, you may gain additional proficiencies through class features, either at level 1 or a later level. For example, the Eldritch Invocation "Beguiling Influence" adds proficiency in Deception and Persuasion skills, if you choose that option. However, to begin with, your character has the four skill proficencies as mentioned.

Four
If you've not used the character building steps here, please make sure you do.
There's 3 sources of skill proficiencies:

Race
Class
Background

Your race as a Silver Dragonborn, unfortunately, grants no skill proficiencies. So 0 from that.
Your class as a Warlock grants you 2 proficiencies from a list of Arcana, Deception, History, Intimidation, Investigation, Nature, or Religion.
Your background as an Outlander grants you proficiency with the Athletics and Survival skills. Additionally, you gain proficiency with one musical instrument.
So your total skill proficiencies are 4 plus 1 additional tool proficiency.

Please note, this answer assumes a 1st level character. If you are a higher level character, you may have features that grant additional proficiencies beyond what's listed here. For example, the Eldritch Invocation Beguiling Influence grants you proficiency with both the Deception and Persuasion skills.
